# Changing the colour of a <b> tag

Tags: javascript, html, css, xhtml

I am trying to change the color of this text to green using JavaScript, but I get a warning about it being a bad object and the script crashes.

```
<html>
<head>

<style>

b   {

    color: #0000FF;
}

</style>

<script>

function resizea()  {

  var a = document.getElementsByTagName("b");
  a.style.color = "#00FF00";
}

</script>

</head>
<body onload="resizea()">

<b>I am blue</b>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can I ask why you're not using CSS for styling??

Comment: For the future please *always* post the *exact* wording of any warnings/errors you get. They can make it *much* easier to diagnose your problem.

Comment: I am maximizing my window and I'm going to make my Java applet consume the entire window so I get maximum size

Comment: is it color or colour :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

since  `getElementsByTagName("b")` return a collection of elements, you need to get the first one:

```
var a = document.getElementsByTagName("b")[0];
```

Note the index between brackets `[0]`

Comment: Great, I haven't seen anything like this before so I wa really stumped.  ty.

Answer (score 2):

A little more verbose way, but hopefully more clear. Go thou all the `b` elements and change their color:

```
  var boldTags = document.getElementsByTagName ("b");

  console.log("There are " + boldTags.length + " bold elements");
  for (var i = 0; i < boldTags.length; i++) {
      var boldTag = boldTags[i]; 
      boldTag.style.color = "#00FF00";
      console.log("Element indexed  " + (i + 1) + " has color of \n" + boldTag.style.color);
   }
```

Comment: And yes as @PenguinCoder suggested you should probably not use JS for styling

Answer (score 1):

If there is more than one `<b>` tag in your page then you can use the following code to change the color of all the bold texts..

```
$("b").attr("style","color:#00FF00;")
```